# How I can place title buttons in the center of page but not in the center between others elements of nav bar

Tags: html

I have a problem, my navbar has 3 elements: logo, main menu with function buttons and authorization menu. I want to position function buttons in the center of the page, but it locates them in the center between the logo and authorization menu. Could u help me fix it?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #808080;">
  <h3 href="{% url 'posts:index' %}"><span style="color:darkblue">Web</span>
    <span style="color:lightblue">TO</span>-<span style="color:lightgreen">DO</span>
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'posts:new_post' %}"><span style="color:white">
        &#10133</span></a>
  {% endif %}
  </h3>
  <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <span style="color:gold">{{ user.username }}.</span></a>
      <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{% url 'password_change' %}">
        <span style="color:white">Изменить пароль</span></a>
      <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{% url 'logout' %}">
        <span style="color:white">Выйти</span></a>
    {% else %}
      <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{% url 'login' %}">
        <span style="color:white">Войти</span></a> |
      <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{% url 'signup' %}">
        <span style="color:white">Регистрация</span></a>
    {% endif %}
  </nav>
</nav>
```

Comment: It's not clear what it is you want to do.  You have no buttons and no logo. Please indicate what the logo is, where your main menu with function buttons are and where the authorization menu is

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of tricks to this.  First the middle element comes last. second make sure the width is the same for the left and right div.  A better way (imo) is to use flexbox

```css
nav{
border:solid 2px black;
}

*{
font-size:3vw;
}
```

```html
<nav><div style='float:left;width:35%;border:solid 1px red;'><h3 id='left'style='float:left;margin:0'>web logo 1234567890</h3></div>

<div style='float:right;text-align:right;width:35%;border:solid 1px red;'>other stuff</div>

<div style='text-align:center;border:solid 1px blue'> special functions</div>
</nav>
```